# Can this HTML written form be written like the scaffold generated Ruby form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Because this was written with Bootstrap in mind, Is it going to prevent me from writing it in Ruby to replace the form that was generated by generating the scaffold ?

HTML/Bootstrap form that I coded

```
   <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputTwitter">Twitter User</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="Twitter User">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputSession">Primary Trading Session</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select name="selTradingSession">
                    <option value"0">U.S. Session</option>
                    <option value"1">European Session</option>
                    <option value"2">Asian Session</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button></div>
        </div>
        <p><small class="text-muted">*We will not give out your email or twitter handle.   </small></p>
    </form>
```

Scaffold Generated form

```
<%= form_for(@softrun) do |f| %>
  <% if @softrun.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@softrun.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this softrun from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @softrun.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :soft_email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :soft_email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :soft_twitter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :soft_twitter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :prim_session %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :prim_session %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Scaffold is just generic boilerplate.  The template is generic bootstrap.  You will have to merge the two together.

When I do template merges, i generally pull the common elements from the bootstrap into partials and then render them in the rails scaffold form.

Comment: What is a partial ? Thanks !

Comment: Partial used for rendering sub templates within the current controller that depends on a single object.

Comment: So My simple fix was to use the command "rails g bootstrap:themed softruns -f " Essentially it did what I was looking for and that was to get a bootstrap form written into ruby. Will this approach hinder any functionality in the future ?